# Unresolved import in PyDev Eclipse (Win7 x64)

Tags: eclipse, pydev

My Eclipse throws unresolved import when I`m trying to import Tkinter. I stumbled on this site: http://klaith.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/pydev-unresolved-import-errors/ ,but none of those tips did really help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is a problem in the PYTHONPATH configuration...

Please provide the details below to help diagnose it:

1. your PYTHONPATH -- you can get it by making: import sys;print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))
2. The place where Tkinter is installed.
3. The actual code that's appearing as unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Tkinter to pythonpath? Whenever you add a new library you have to update that.
Go to Window->Preferences->PyDev->Intepreter, under libraries add the path to the module. You could do the same for the project by right clicking on it, going to properties and updating it there, but that python path will only be used for that project.

Comment: Didn`t help, import still does not see Tkinter even after adding the tkinter folder to pythonpath.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem.  After ensuring the library(ies) are added to your `PYTHONPATH`, you may need to **restart** your IDE before the errors actually disappear.  I don't know why that worked, but it did for me.